# Multiple Edges in Visual Library of Netbeans RCP

Tags: netbeans

I want to make 2 edges between 2 nodes (pins) visibly separated.
Having that for one Edge, the code is like that (abviously):

```
addEdge(link);
setEdgeSource(link, sourecObject);
setEdgeTarget(link, targetObject);
```

Where link is object extending `ConnectionWidget`.
Is there any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply **overrided** `paintWidget` method and called `drawLine()` 2 times.